# Apply when conditional to nested lists with Ansible, not just to top-level one

Tags: amazon-ec2, scripting, ansible

So I have this killer problem with Ansible + AWS EC2.

If disk type is 'io1', 'iops' should be specified, otherwise they should not be specified.
If I want to make disk type configurable, I have to apply when, but it does not work:

```
- name: Provision AWS Instances
  ec2:
    instance_type: "{{ ec2_instance_type }}"
    image: "{{ ec2_ami_id }}"
    ...
    volumes:
      - device_name: "{{ ec2_root_disk_name }}"
        volume_type: "{{ ec2_root_disk_type }}"
        volume_size: "{{ ec2_root_disk_size }}"
        delete_on_termination: "{{ ec2_root_disk_delete_on_termination }}"
        iops: "{{ ec2_root_disk_iops }}"
        when: ec2_root_disk_type == 'io1'
      - device_name: "{{ ec2_root_disk_name }}"
        volume_type: "{{ ec2_root_disk_type }}"
        volume_size: "{{ ec2_root_disk_size }}"
        delete_on_termination: "{{ ec2_root_disk_delete_on_termination }}"
        when: ec2_root_disk_type != 'io1'
```

But, this nested 'when' condition is not processed and drive is added twice:

```
"volumes": [
    {
        "delete_on_termination": "true", 
        "device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
        "iops": "100", 
        "volume_size": "30", 
        "volume_type": "gp2", 
        "when": "ec2_root_disk_type == 'io1'"
    }, 
    {
        "delete_on_termination": "true", 
        "device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
        "volume_size": "30", 
        "volume_type": "gp2", 
        "when": "ec2_root_disk_type != 'io1'"
    }, 
]
```

I could add 'when' to whole command, except that I may have up to 5 drives so it will mean copying it over 32 times.

Is it possible to make Ansible process 'when' on nested lists?

Is it possible to assemble this list in a variable, refer to it in this command? Documentation of Ansible is silent on non-string, structured variables. Maybe I can apply collection filtering somehow?

What's recommended course of action here? I imagine everyone will be bumping in this exact problem when they try creating volumes of configurable type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually ended up adding an empty custom python module to `library/` and a corresponding action plugin to `action_plugins/` of my playbook. In this plugin I process input arguments by forming volumes list that I need, and call `ec2` with improved arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Specify volumes in the inventory, not in the play.

For instance, the `group_vars/with_iops.yml` file:

```
volumes:
  - device_name: "{{ ec2_root_disk_name }}"
    volume_type: "{{ ec2_root_disk_type }}"
    volume_size: "{{ ec2_root_disk_size }}"
    delete_on_termination: "{{ ec2_root_disk_delete_on_termination }}"
    iops: "{{ ec2_root_disk_iops }}"
```

The `group_vars/without_iops.yml` file:

```
volumes:
  - device_name: "{{ ec2_root_disk_name }}"
    volume_type: "{{ ec2_root_disk_type }}"
    volume_size: "{{ ec2_root_disk_size }}"
    delete_on_termination: "{{ ec2_root_disk_delete_on_termination }}"
```

The play:

```
- name: Provision AWS Instances
  ec2:
    instance_type: "{{ ec2_instance_type }}"
    image: "{{ ec2_ami_id }}"
    ...
    volumes: "{{ volumes }}"
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but now I have two configuration files. I can't get variables from yml (can I?) so I basically need do the configuration twice.

Comment: Yes, you have two configuration files: one for the group of hosts that need iops, and one for the group of hosts that does not.  And YES, the variables in those yaml files are accessible for the hosts in those groups.

Comment: I think I can list all disks in a single .yml file
How do I refer to a given volume from a jinja2? E.g. can I do {{ volumes[1].volume_size }} etc?

Comment: Just because you CAN do something does not make it a Good Idea.  You have some hosts that need iops, and others that don't, right?

Comment: No, I want to make it entirely configurable via group_vars

Comment: Do some hosts need iops and others don't need it?

Comment: No, the every host has up to 5 drives, some of which may be IOPS. All hosts then share identical layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211280/discussion-between-jack-and-alamar).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inline condition such as:

```
- device_name: "{{ ec2_root_disk_name }}"
  volume_type: "{{ ec2_root_disk_type }}"
  volume_size: "{{ ec2_root_disk_size }}"
  delete_on_termination: "{{ ec2_root_disk_delete_on_termination }}"
  iops: "{{ ec2_root_disk_iops if ec2_root_disk_type == 'io1' }}"
```

Comment: That's nice, but can I also make the whole device (list item) optional? I want to have optional drives. I will surely check that one.

Comment: If I do `ec2_root_disk_iops if ec2_root_disk_type == 'io1' else ''` then property is still present in resulting JSON and AWS invocation still fails. If I do `else 0`, still fails. AWS does not want this property at all if type != 'io1'.